# Attribute values in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have 2 attributes in my product 1 is model and 2 is manufacturer.
I want to search on behalf of these 2 attributes with 2 drop down.
User will select and the results will show accordingly.
How can I achieve this in Magento 2?

Comment: can you please explain your question properly?

Comment: https://www.simplyheadsets.com.au/jabra-pro-920-wireless-headset.html open this url and click on "Does this headset work with my phone?" i want same